# Discord bot not running on repl.it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am not able to run my bot on repl.it anymore, I keep getting the same traceback whenever I kill the console and rerun it and I don't know what the issue is.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 308, in <module>
    client.run(token)
  File "/home/runner/Kurumi-Tokisaki-Bot-TRK/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/Kurumi-Tokisaki-Bot-TRK/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/runner/Kurumi-Tokisaki-Bot-TRK/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/runner/Kurumi-Tokisaki-Bot-TRK/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 589, in login
    await self.setup_hook()
  File "main.py", line 35, in setup_hook
    await self.tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(id = 1009907559391567912))
  File "/home/runner/Kurumi-Tokisaki-Bot-TRK/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1070, in sync
    data = await self._http.bulk_upsert_guild_commands(self.client.application_id, guild.id, payload=payload)
  File "/home/runner/Kurumi-Tokisaki-Bot-TRK/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 738, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
```

I even tried changing the token but it gives me the same traceback.

Comment: Maybe I'm out of date, but don't discord bots have to be run on the server running discord?

Comment: Make sure your bot has the correct permissions in the developer portal. `50001` typically means some scope is missing, more likely `applications.commands` than not.

Comment: @iced I'm not sure what the issue is since I checked developer portal and the scopes are the same as how I left them and a few days earlier I was having problems with rate limits too so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I would first try and host it locally instead of on Replit, so you can eliminate the possibility of that being blocked or rate-limited. Additionally, generate a new OAuth2 invite link with the proper scopes, and double-check your token is correct.

Comment: Try checking that the library is up to date, and you also need the commands scope in order to add commands.

Comment: Check that the guild ID 1009907559391567912 is correct and that the bot is in the server and has permission to create commands in the server